GDK Backend: wayland (HelloWorldGuiApp:91366):Gtk-WARNING **: 22:44:58.503: cannot open display: :0
I am creating a simple hello world GUI app using .net and sdk and when I am converting it into a snap and running it I am getting this error at first I do added the x11 package but I want my appliction to only use wayland sever for display as I am building this application for ubuntu core.
GDK Backend: wayland (HelloWorldGuiApp:91366):Gtk-WARNING **: 22:44:58.503: cannot open display: :0

This is my snapcraft.yaml for my .net apk.
{
name: helloworldguiapp

base: core22

version: ‘1.0’

summary: A simple Hello World GUI app

description: | This is a simple .NET Gtk# Hello World GUI application designed to run in kiosk mode using ubuntu-frame.

grade: stable

confinement: strict

architectures:

build-on: amd64
build-on: arm64
apps:

helloworldguiapp:

command: HelloWorldGuiApp
daemon: simple
restart-condition: always
plugs:
  - wayland
  - opengl
  - network
  - content[graphics-core22]  # Added the missing graphics-core22 plug
environment:
  WAYLAND_DISPLAY: wayland-0
parts:

helloworldguiapp:

plugin: dotnet
dotnet-build-configuration: Release
dotnet-self-contained-runtime-identifier: linux-x64
source: .
build-packages:
  - dotnet-sdk-8.0
stage-packages:
  - libgtk-3-0
  - libglib2.0-0
  - libwayland-client
}

what changes should I do to my yaml file?
I try running the .net snap on ubuntu core and I expected it to open the hello world gui on ubuntu core but it resulted with this warning=>
GDK Backend: wayland (HelloWorldGuiApp:91366):Gtk-WARNING **: 22:44:58.503: cannot open display: :0



2024-11-22T13:05:06Z -[29742]: Settings portal not found: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY

This looks as though your app is trying to use desktop portals. But there is no desktop session. If your app won't run without dbus, look at the Qt example.

2024-11-22T13:05:06Z helloworld-gui-app.daemon[29742]: xkbcommon: ERROR: failed to add default include path /usr/share/X11/xkb

That looks like an attempt to access an XKB_CONFIG_ROOT outside the snap, that won't work on a core system where the expected files won't exist. Try adding this to your app.environment:
XKB_CONFIG_ROOT: $SNAP/usr/share/X11/xkb

You may also need to stage xkb-data if that isn't already being pulled in.

2024-11-22T13:05:09Z systemd[1]: snap.helloworld-gui-app.daemon.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV

Well, possibly as a result of the above, your application segfaulted.

Is .net isn't supported to use only wayland? Is .net not supported for gui application for ubuntu-core?

There's no obvious reason this can't work. But apps may need some configuring to get them working with snap confinement.

I don’t know about the .net parts but, as it appears to be based on gtk, this should be a good start:
https://mir-server.io/docs/packaging-a-gtk3-application-as-an-iot-gui

Thanks for the reply Alan , I used the guide and updated my yaml file and now its working properly in desktop using frame-it but when I am trying to run it on ubuntu core even though I am not getting any warning and my daemon is active and enabled its not displaying on the machine and using snap logs I am getting these errors.

2024-11-22T13:05:06Z -[29742]: Settings portal not found: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
2024-11-22T13:05:06Z helloworld-gui-app.daemon[29742]: xkbcommon: ERROR: failed to add default include path /usr/share/X11/xkb
2024-11-22T13:05:09Z systemd[1]: snap.helloworld-gui-app.daemon.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV

2024-11-22T13:05:09Z systemd[1]: snap.helloworld-gui-app.daemon.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
2024-11-22T13:05:12Z systemd[1]: snap.helloworld-gui-app.daemon.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 117.
2024-11-22T13:05:12Z systemd[1]: Started snap.helloworld-gui-app.daemon.service - Service for snap application helloworld-gui-app.daemon.
2024-11-22T13:05:12Z helloworld-gui-app.daemon[29851]: GDK Backend:

Is .net isn't supported to use only wayland?
Is .net not supported for gui application for ubuntu-core?
